# Is ng-class directive condition always displayed in DOM?

Tags: angularjs

I'm completely new in AngularJS. I wrote this code:

```
<div ng-class="myString != 'true' ? 'class-one' : 'class-two'">
  // my code that I want to display
</div>
```

And I noticed that this condition is displayed in the developer tools. Is this a default behavior by AngularJS or I'm just doing something wrong?

Maybe there is a possibility to just apply those classes dynamically without showing its condition in the dom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a default behavior by AngularJS or I'm just doing something wrong?

No it is not the default behavior

The correct syntax of `ng-class` is this:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'class-one': myString == 'true' , 'class-two': myString != 'true' }">
```

Another way is to use `class` and the ternary expression as you wrote it:

```
<div class="{{ myString != 'true' ? 'class-one' : 'class-two' }}">
```